# Jquery UI Datepicker refresh issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have used jquery ui datepicker in my application. It is working fine for the first time, but failing to refresh the page after navigating to another page.Datepicker not working when i come to the datepicker page.

```
@model FloorPlanner.Models.AuditViewModel
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script>

    var startdate;
    var enddate;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker(
      {
          dateFormat: 'yy, mm , dd',
          onSelect: function () {
              startdate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
              startdate = (startdate.getFullYear()) + '/' + (startdate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (startdate.getDate());
   }
      })
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker(
          {
              dateFormat: 'yy, mm , dd',
              onSelect: function () {
                  enddate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                  enddate = (enddate.getFullYear()) + '/' + (enddate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (enddate.getDate() + 1);
              }
          })

        });
        $("#auditfilter").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Floor/AuditFilter',
                data: {
                    startDate: startdate,
                    endDate: enddate
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#divTOPutPartialViewIn').html(data);
                },
                error: function (data)
                {
                    alert("select date");
                },
                complete: function () { }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm fp-btn-group-float-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="showTree">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body fp-container-panel-body">
        <table class="input-group" style="padding-left: 5px;" border="0">
            <tr><td >Start Date
                <input type="text" id="datepicker"style="Height: 30px"/></td>
                <td style="padding-left: 10px">End Date <input type="text" id="datepicker2"style="Height: 30px" /></td>
                <td style="Height: 16px "><input id="auditfilter" type="button" value="Audit Trail" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <div id="divTOPutPartialViewIn">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui") *@
```

I have tried destroying the datepicker in document ready function also tried refresh in the same, nothing working, it is working only if i do the entire application refresh by pressing F5.

I have included the js,css files in bundle config.

Thanks

Comment: $(function () {and document.ready are same and you don't need it multiple times. remove all and keep only one and put your required code inside it.

Comment: yeah i did . still i have the same problem any help??

Comment: What does this means `but failing to refresh the page after navigating to another page.Datepicker not working when i come to the datepicker page.` ? Please explain briefly and add that explanation into your question

Comment: datepicker is working fine only when i load the application. when i try to use datepicker after moving on to some other page(navigation), it is acting like a text box.It works fine only when i reload the application

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var startdate;
var enddate;
            $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-100:-18Y",
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                minDate: '-100Y',
                maxDate: '-18Y'
            });
         $("#datepicker2").datepicker(
          {
              dateFormat: 'yy, mm , dd',
              onSelect: function () {
                  enddate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                  enddate = (enddate.getFullYear()) + '/' + (enddate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (enddate.getDate() + 1);
              }
});
```

you have used function(){ $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker()} in the document.ready(function(){}). so the datepicker function() will work only on document ready. i think this is your problem. try it. may be work.

Comment: didnt understand? i have used two datepickers. one for start date and other for end date, can you please explain bit in details

Comment: remove 8th line $(function () {}) this will only work when document ready. if you define datepicker on function() it will work only on refresh or page load. i think this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move your `<script>` tags to the bottom of the page to ensure the DOM has fully loaded before attempting to select elements or modify with jQuery.

Next, In your `$(document).ready(function() { });` you have the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function()) {
        $("#DateOfBirth")
    }

    $(function()) {
        $("#datepicker2")
    }
});
```

Remove both of the `$(function()) { }` that are wrapping your `.datepicker()` calls and everything should work okay.

It should just look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({ 
        //other stuff here
    });


    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        //other stuff here
    });
});
```

Comment: i have removed the  $(function()) {} and placed the script at the bottom but still my probelm has not resolved.after navigation to another page and when return back my datepicker is like textbox..not showing calender.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors logged in the Javascript console?